# What kind of algorithm should I use to build ML model that can predict just next reoccurence of an event in the future (at irregular time interval)?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, time-series, forecasting, survival-analysis

I'm quite new to machine learning and statistics.

I've a dataset from some ecommerce sale's history. It's almost 2k instances, and features include personId (string), productCategory (string/discrete), amountPaid (float/continuous), purchaseTime (string/Time(DD/MM/YYYY)). Person can purchase product at any time (irregular time interval so I can't use time series analysis, I guess).

I want to know when will the same person (attr with person Id) make just next purchase in a category (attr with productCategory). What ML model should I use for this problem? Should I use Time Series forcasting or Survival Analysis or maybe some other function? How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Survival Analysis would be a common way to approach it. One way to model it would be to predict time-to-purchase where the prior is already purchased.